# GCM Unregistration Time

Tags: android, google-play, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

We are having issues with our clients being unregistered randomly, typically 1 hour after registration occurs but has been up to 3 or 4 hours. We are trying to determine when the unregistration is happening so we can identify the bug.

So I am aware that the unregistration process for GCM generally takes about 1 hour. That being said, is it unheard of for unregistration to take **longer than 1 hour**.

This is fairly important because if it always takes somewhere in the range of 50-70 minutes as I have typically seen, then it means unregistration is occuring immediately for our clients. That would rule out a large amount of scenarios where our device may be getting unregistered.

So the question to reitterate is: Is there a guaranteed time that GCM unregistration will fall under? Can I **guarantee** for instance that GCM will have unregistered my device if I tell it to unregister, 2 hours afer I make the call (2 hours as an example).

Comment: It's not clear what you want to know. Does it really matter how long it takes GCM to unregister after you tell it to unregister? Do you have code that requests GCM to unregister? If you do, please post it. If the clients get unregistered without your code requesting it, that's something completely different. I encountered a situation in which the broadcast receiver got a REGISTRATION intent with `unregistered` extra when it should have received a RECEIVE intent with a message. Perhaps you should add writing to log file in your broadcast receiver, do see if you have a similar problem.

Comment: @Eran So basically our devices are getting unregistered *without us requesting it* but we aren't sure what/where the bug is. Theres no intent being fired back to tell us that something occured. We are trying to narrow down the scope of where the bug COULD be occuring. So part of this is knowing how long a device takes to get unregistered. If a device always gets unregistered in about an hour, but we get unregistered after 3 hours, then that means that its not exclusive to when the registration occurs.

Comment: Are you sure your GCM broadcast receiver is not called when the un-registration occurs? In the case I experienced, the unregistration happened when we sent a message to the device. It happened on older Android versions (2.2, 2.3).

Comment: @Eran quite sure, or atleast as sure as I can be when I have a log set for every type of intent the GCM Broadcast Receiver can hear. That being said, I am interested to know why sending am essage to your device was unregistering it.

Comment: I can't be entirely sure, since I only developed the server side, and the app was developed by one of our clients, and I didn't have access to their code. However, from what I heard, they used PhoneGap to develop their app, and somehow the build process changed the package name of their app, thus causing GCM not to work properly (since the GCM definitions in the manifest depend on the app package name). The problem happened only on older Android versions, because for some reason newer versions ignore the package name in GCM definitions in the manifest.